# in sybase ,after database password encryption ,not able to connect

Tags: database-connection, sybase, dbvisualizer

Our sybase db password has been recently encrypted and post that i am not able to connect to db . i use Db Visualizer  7.1.4. I have tried changing the *jar*s , then JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS setting  but nothing seems to work .Please help.

```
error :JZ0LA: Failed to instantiate Cipher object. Transformation RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding is not implemented by any of the loaded JCE providers.
```

Details:

- Type: java.sql.SQLException
- Error Code: 0
- SQL State: JZ0LA

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Sybase ASE, there is a way to reset the password when you've locked yourself out. If you're running Sybase SQL Anywhere or Sybase IQ, there is not.
Please clarify exactly what you're running.

Answer (score 0):

its sybases ASE. its not that the password is locked out coz its working for certain set of people.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is about passwords being encrypted over the network, you need to look at:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.jconnect/FD0XHvdVV6I

We don't use your client, but I'd say you probably need to be using jconn4.jar (I couldn't get jconn3 going with net password encryption for any of our clients, though it's supposed to work.)  Then you need the Eccpresso encryption jars (they come with Sybase Open Client.)

I can't help how you set them up with Db Visualiser, but you'll probably have to get some properties set up wherever you do that in that app, something like:

```
ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true 
JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom
```

There does seem to be help on the db visualiser site though:

https://support.dbvis.com/support/solutions/articles/1000231934-how-to-enable-password-encryption

Comment: How to add these properties to hibernate.cfg.xml file?`ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true 
JCE_PROVIDER_CLASS=com.certicom.ecc.jcae.Certicom`